# Setting field value from spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

HOw can i set a hidden input field value(in jsp) from spring  Controller?

Comment: Just as any other input field, for example using `<form:hidden path="myBean.myAttribute" />`. Please provide your form and your controller code.

Comment: If your controller is sending the value to jsp and to forward to anohter controller with hidden this is the way..<form:input type="hidden" path="myBean.myAttribute" />..we can suggest something if you show the code...

Comment: @PratapMurukutla `<form:input type="hidden" />` can (should?) be replaced by `<form:hidden />`.

Comment: i don't want to declare it into bean...i meant,simply ,when control comes to controller,setting hidden field value say "1" before returning to jsp..so that i can use this hidden field value

Comment: can you explain more detail exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: the type hidden is used when you want to send the data from one controller to other controller through jsp..otherwise the data can not be rendered to another controller...Do you want to set the variable value coming from controller and want to use in jsp..

Comment: @sp00m yeah your method is also correct..i tried in my application it works.my answer is duplicate

Comment: yes..i want to set the variable value coming from controller and want to use in jsp.

Comment: Set it as a request attribute in your controller or add it to your `Model` if your controller returns a `ModelAndView`, then in the JSP: `<input type="hidden" name="myfield" value="${requestAttr}"/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take some value (id) from database (with findAllIdForUsers() method) and forward to your JSP with model:

```
@Autowired
ServiceInterface service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "example.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewUsers(Model model){       
    model.addAttribute("usersId", service.findAllIdForUsers());
    return "example";
    }
```

On JSP you can set this id's on some button:

```
<c:forEach items="${ requestScope['users'] }" var="users">

<form action="<%=response.encodeURL(request.getContextPath() + "delete.html") %>" method="POST"> 
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<c:out value="${ usersId.id }"/>" />
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Delete User" /></form>
</c:forEach>
```

And then on button click you can sent id to another controller and work or delete this user:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "delete.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteUser(@RequestParam("id") int id, Model model) {
    service.delete(id);
    model.addAttribute("usersId", service.findAllIdForUsers());
        return "example";
    }
```